# Como fazer CRUD no Joomla

Tags: joomla, cms

eu sei inserir dados pelo formulário com o chrono froms, mais gostaria de saber como listar, deletar, fazer update e gerar relatorios de dados de uma tabela no Joomla, não acho material sobre isso , se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: O SOPT não é um lugar para se pedir tutoriais, aqui o pessoal ajuda a resolver problemas e tirar dúvidas, recomendo que faça uma busca no Google e caso tenha alguma duvida no processo, ai então faça uma pergunta colocando junto o código com o problema especifico.

Answer (score 1):

Para criar um componente usando o CMS Joomla, você pode seguir a documentação oficial disponível em https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component.

Existem algumas documentações até em português, porém tendem a estarem desatualizadas.